# Can I silently load javascript or image files in the background?

Tags: javascript

My application has a very simple main page which serves as a login gateway. The users must go to this page first. The page has no jQuery, a very small javascript file and a small CSS file. It loads quickly.

While the user is focusing on the screen and starting to enter login details or reading the title and other information I would like to make the most of this time by pre-loading some images, CSS or javascript to be ready for when the user has logged in and goes to the next screen.

Is there a way I can do this silently (hopefully without the user seeing on the bottom of the screen as the resources are loading). I just want to load even a couple of files to minimize the time it takes to open the next screen.

Comment: Look for .on event on the login input and fetch the resources you want then?

Comment: @cggaurav there's no such event as "live".  Did you mean "focus"?

Comment: @cggaurav Telling the poster to use .live()? Did you read the question!

Comment: @epascarello: [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live)?  I think you mean [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I was repeating what cggaurav had before he edited his comment to something a little better.

Comment: @epascarello: Oops.  I pointed my comment at the wrong person.  It should've been towards cggaurav. >.>

Comment: @Melina - please either post your solution answer or accept one of the answers given!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by putting image path in your CSS class. So loading CSS class will also load images. Similarly you can pre-load images using javascript as well.

Below is sample snippet from my project; here images are getting loaded using jquery. You can do same in pure javascript as well.

```
  loadImages : function(){
    this.picBaseUrl = BASE_URL + this.id + '/';  //base path for all images
    $('#p1').attr('src', this.picBaseUrl + '1.jpg');
    $('#p2').attr('src', this.picBaseUrl + '2.jpg');
    $('#p3').attr('src', this.picBaseUrl + '3.jpg');
    $('#p4').attr('src', this.picBaseUrl + '4.jpg');
    $('#p5').attr('src', this.picBaseUrl + '5.jpg');
}
```

so here i have loaded 5 images. Just make sure to call this method whenever you want to load these images.

Answer (score 1):

in the < head >:

```
<script src='' id="s1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

at the end of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s1 = document.getElementById("s1");
s1.src= "myJavaScript.js";
</script>
</body>
```

you can load all your resourses in the myJavaScript.js and they will be loaded AFTER your page  has been complitely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Loading images can be done this way:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
     //image loaded
};
img.src = "image.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery, I think using the onload event for the body tag. so something like (untested):

```
<script>
function preLoad() {

document.getElementById("img1").src = "/images/image1toPreload.png";
document.getElementById("img2").src = "/images/image2toPreload.png";
document.getElementById("img3").src = "/images/image3toPreload.png";
}
</script>

...

<body onload="preLoad()">

your content here
...

<img style="display:none" id="img1"/>
<img style="display:none" id="img2"/>
<img style="display:none" id="img3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create n divs on your page, 1 for each cached image,  then define the css for them.

```
#Div1 {
background: url(path/cachedImage1.png) no-repeat;
display: none;
}
#Div2 {
background: url(path/cachedImage2.png) no-repeat;
display: none;
}
#Div3 {
background: url(path/cachedImage3.png) no-repeat;
display: none;
}
```